# CSS not loading correctly on cloud-flare

Tags: css, render

I have developed my portfolio and locally everything works good, though when I upload it on my hosting the CSS renders differently.

I have hard refreshed on Chrome and tried also on Firefox, but still stays different.

What can be the problem and the solution?

This is my [network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuW7o.png)

Thanks!

Comment: are you using cdn ? or provide exact path to your css files

Comment: Yes I'm using Cloudflare..
The CSS path is correct

Comment: How does it render differently? Is the CSS in a style block or in  a seperate file? If in a seperate file, is it downloaded (checking in browser tools)?  Have you flushed  your cache? Perhaps show an example of your code, hard to debug without it.

Comment: CSS is auto cached by Cloudflare when it is on, try putting “.css?newcache0x” in your html tag, where X you add +1 everytime you change something in your CSS file, so it will create a new cache.

Example:
< link rel=“stylesheet” href="…/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css?newcache01" >

Comment: and please add a screenshot of your network tab need to check is that your css files are loading properly or not

Comment: The one from @Pardeep worked, but I wonder, now I have to change the number every time I change my .css? Is there an automatic way to get it done?

Comment: okay sure let me post the answer then

Comment: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache-

Answer (score 1):

CSS is auto cached by Cloudflare when it is on, try putting “.css?newcache0x” in your HTML tag, where X you add +1 every time you change something in your CSS file, so it will create a new cache.

**Example:**
< link rel=“stylesheet” href="…/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css?newcache01" >